# Command line parameter in C

Tags: c, parameters

I get segmentation error when I give my program parameter '2' or '3'. It should print That's number two/three. What's the error here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (*argv[2] == '2') {
            printf("That's number two!");
        }       
        else if (*argv[2] == '3') {
            printf("That's number 3!");
        }   

        else
            printf("Error.\n");
    }
    else
        printf("No input given.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I type ./Test 2 or 3. I can't find a error, and gcc does not give errors / warnings either.
Thanks.

Comment: Try: `if (*argv[1] == '2')`

Comment: index beign at 0; use `argv[1]`.

Comment: `if (argc > 1) {` is the wrong pre-test for the later `if (*argv[2] ==...`.  Should be `if (argc > 2) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (*argv[1] == '2') {
        printf("That's number two!");
    }       
    else if (*argv[1] == '3') {
        printf("That's number 3!");
    }
```

Index begins with 0.

argv[0] is the name of the program and argv[1] is the first command line parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array:

```
argv[0] // the name of the executable
argv[1] // the first argument
argv[...]
```

When you do:

```
if (*argv[2] == '2')
```

and you were called with `./Test 2`, there is only a single argument, so `argv[2]` is an out-of-bounds access.

For more information, see [main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).